# Paramaterized abstract factory in Autofac

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, factory, autofac

I want to be able to register a factory component in Autofac with the following properties:

1. The factory must take a parameter (in this case a string), and return a component instance that is specifically related to that string
2. The component's lifetime must be InstancePerLifetimeScope
3. The implication of #2 is that the 2nd call to the factory with a particular parameter value will return the same component instance within a lifetime scope.

I have been able to achieve this by writing some code which acts as a "name registry" within the lifetime scope, keeping a dictionary of names and component instances which have been created.  This works, but I suspect there might be a way to do this using some autofac registration magic, but I haven't been to crack it yet.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want Autofac [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html#named-and-keyed-services).

Comment: That's just the ticket, knew it would be in there somewhere.  Thanks!

Comment: Links has changed:
http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html